# Apache poi XWPFRun doesn't have isDoubleStrikeThrough method

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

Now i'm using poi 3.11.

org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.CharacterRun (for *.doc files) has both isStrikeThrough() and isDoubleStrikeThrough(),
but org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFRun(for *.docx files) has only isStrike() method.

Why?

it seems that isStrike() method can't detect double-struck state.

i know that double-struck state can be detected with this implementation below

```
instanceOfXWPFRun.getCTR().getRPr().isSetDstrike()
```

but it is not pleasant for me. Are there any unified interfaces, classes or methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a newer version of Apache POI. (3.12 beta 1 will do you when it's out, for now a nightly / svn build)

If you look at the [latest JavaDocs for XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html), you'll see that there are methods [isDoubleStrikeThrough()](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#isDoubleStrikeThrough()) and [setDoubleStrikethrough(boolean)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#setDoubleStrikethrough(boolean))

These two are also available on the common [CharacterRun interface](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/wp/usermodel/CharacterRun.html), which is shared between HWPF's `CharacterRun` and XWPF's `XWPFRun`

Comment: fantastic!  CharacterRun interface is what i want.

Comment: isStrikeThrough and isDoubleStrikeThrough in poi-src-3.12-beta1-20150206 worked fine!
the next cause of my headaches is an implementation of Apache Tika...